# Wordpress Dev: Understanding Scope of plugins or general WP Architecture

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to understand a bit about how WordPress works in development..
I already created some shortcodes that I can just edit in on my page and some WIdgets that seem to display on every site or blog post that I created...

My question is: What is the general scope of the widgets or plugins in WordPress that I create? I know there are hooks and WordPress API functions to only show them on specific parts of WordPress, e.g on the admin-panel, or just in the widget sidebar of a page...

But are there some good sources about the architecture and scopes of how and where to use your plugins? Are they kind of injected into every page I create on my WP pages? (e.g with enqueue_scripts or so?). It's just a bit too overwhelming for me as a beginner to get a good overview...

And how are those functions from WP API made accessible in my plugin files/folders when I never imported them? I guess it's based on some module technique but no idea how..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good to delve your feet into the WordPress (WP) new concept called blocks you can find all the details here: [Block Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/)

Creating widgets and shortcodes is a way older process nowadays most people keep their eyes on WordPress Blocks and especially FSE (Full Site Editor) therefore I would suggest you start learning that thing ASAP.

Let's come to your queries:

### How WordPress works technically

Go to your WordPress directory you will find the file called `index.php` which is responsible for bootstrapping your application

Along with the `index.php` you will find a few directories called

1. wp-admin
2. wp-includes
3. wp-content

### wp-admin

Where WP have all functionalities happening in the admin part are executed by accessing classes and functions present inside of this directory

### wp-includes

This directory has all the utility and helper classes and functions

### wp-content

This is the only directory developer can add/edit the files which store all of your plugins, themes, uploads, and other custom directories if your
code or any other plugin code created

[For more details on how WP works](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-wordpress-actually-works-behind-the-scenes-infographic/)

It's quite a challenge to explain all the ins and outs WP in a single post but you can find the detailed explanation in the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/)

WordPress mainly depends on hooks and hooks are come under any of these two categories:

1. action hook
2. filter hook

[For more details on WP hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/)

### How do plugins or themes work?

Both plugins and themes have a terminology called headers using that header metadata WP fills all the details in the plugins listing admin page and in themes listing page

[For more details on header](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/header-requirements/)

Themes mainly depend on the concept called loops which responsible for fetching the posts data and build the necessary details using template tags and iterate them using the loop. Based on the type of page the user visited WP uses the template hierarchy to render the page as per the request that happened on the client end.

[For more details on how WP loops works](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/)

[For more details on how template hierarchy works](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

### Headless CMS

Yes, you can make your complete WP into a headless CMS with the help of WP [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/). The REST API is used to access WordPress outside of the WP for e.g. if your android app need to fetch any posts or categories or user from WP using this REST API it can do that. Also you can create your [custom endpoints too](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#examples)

---

Additionally, try to explore [WP CLI](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/)

I believe that I covered most of the things required to understand how WP works, to be clear this post abstracted many of the things to make it as compact as possible for anyone who started entering into the WP development.

If you like to know more of these abstract explanation in a detailed way then always visit the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/)

If your ide have an auto-complete feature please try to explore all of these functions (wildcard list) which contains most of the security functions provided by WP

1. is_*
2. exists_*
3. validate_*
4. sanitize_*
5. esc_*
6. *kses*
7. *nonce*

Comment: wow thanks, thats quite a lot of hints to start with :)

Comment: I believe covered a few of the core essentials left many things to make you comfortable with WP especially the JS modules and WP react components.